# How to place an icon next to tab title (bootstrap-vue)

Tags: tabs, vuejs2, bootstrap-4

I would like to know if there's a way to place an icon next to the tab titles with vue-bootstrap? Cant seem to find any documentation about it.

I tried using `headHtml` which does work but doesn't make my tab titles reactive to click events anymore.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

This is working for me, using Vue-bootstrap's slot fucntionality.

```js
<b-tabs>
      <b-tab active >
        <template slot="title">
          Overall
          <b-badge variant="light">545</b-badge>
        </template>
        <p>
          I'm the Overall tab
        </p>
      </b-tab>
</b-tabs>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can place html string right in the title prop.
Read here https://github.com/bootstrap-vue/bootstrap-vue/issues/979

Answer (score 0):

Vue-bootstrap provides a slot fucntionality for title.

```html
<div>
  <b-tabs>
    <b-tab active>
      <template v-slot:title>
        <b-spinner type="grow" small></b-spinner> I'm <i>Custom</i> <strong>Title</strong>
      </template>
      <p class="p-3">Tab Contents 1</p>
    </b-tab>

    <b-tab>
      <template v-slot:title>
        <b-spinner type="border" small></b-spinner> Tab 2
      </template>
      <p class="p-3">Tab Contents 2</p>
    </b-tab>
  </b-tabs>
</div><div>
  <b-tabs>
    <b-tab active>
      <template v-slot:title>
        <b-spinner type="grow" small></b-spinner> I'm <i>Custom</i> <strong>Title</strong>
      </template>
      <p class="p-3">Tab Contents 1</p>
    </b-tab>

    <b-tab>
      <template v-slot:title>
        <b-spinner type="border" small></b-spinner> Tab 2
      </template>
      <p class="p-3">Tab Contents 2</p>
    </b-tab>
  </b-tabs>
</div>
```

Check https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/tabs/#add-custom-content-to-tab-title